# Best way to encrypt app.config for use on another computer

Tags: c#, winforms, database-connection, rsa, app-config

I know these kind of questions have been asked several times, but I couldn't find an answer telling pros and cons of the available methods.
I have a winforms app I want to deploy to customers worldwide. I'm using a setup dialog (InstallShield). I want to protect my connection strings in app.config.

So far, I tested following methods and they both worked for me (simple test without using Install Dialog).
Is there a preferred one and is this really still the standard way to go?

I tested these 2 approaches:

1. run aspnet_regiis: [MSDN example](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/previous-versions/aspnet/2w117ede%28v%3Dvs.100%29#granting-read-access-to-an-rsa-encryption-key)

   - rename app.config to web.config
   - encrypt the config on development computer,
   - rename web.config to app.config
   - Export the key as keys.xml.
   - Import the keys.xml on customer computer: run aspnet_regiis on customer computer.
   - delete the key
2. configSection.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider"); [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.configuration.sectioninformation.protectsection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

   - config needs to be encryted running a program/code at customer side
   - can be easily done in Install Dialog

Method 2 seems to be very insecure to me as I can copy the encrypted .config file and decrypt it with another program calling UnprotectSection().

Method 1 requires IIS, but seems to be relatively secure to me, if the keys.xml is not fetched. I hope this can be realized in Install Dialog.

Are there any disadvantages I'm missing?

Comment: Is there anyone with an advice for me? Are my assumptions correct? Is IIS a problem?